# Java Main - Calling another method

Tags: java

I have the following code below:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
start();
}
```

i get this error: Non-static method start() cannot be referenced from a static context.

How can i go about doing this?

Comment: May I suggest a beginner's book on Java? Or at least going through the tutorials available from Oracle? Your question indicates you really don't have a firm grasp on the most basic of concepts and either would really help.

Comment: How do you declare your start ()?

Answer (score 7):

Create an instance of your class and call the `start` method of that instance.
If your class is named Foo then use the following code in your `main` method:

```
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.start();
```

Alternatively, make method `start` static, by declaring it as static.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this can help you..

```
public class testProgarm {

    private static void start() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

}
```

However, it is not a good practice to make a method static. You should instantiate a object and call a object's method instead. If your object does't have a state, or you need to implement a helper method, static is the way to go.

Comment: "However, it is not a good practice to make a method static." This really depends. If you don't have state, or you need to implement a helper method, static is the way to go.

Comment: @Oliver: Thanks and agree, put your answer in my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create an instance of another class within the main method, for example `newClass` and call the `start()` method within it.

```
newClass class = new newClass();
class.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

> For non-static (& instance) methods, you may need an instance
>   of class to access it.

Try this:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();

       TestClass tc = new TestClass();
       tc.start1()
    }

    // Static method
    private static void start() {
        System.out.println("start");
    }

    // Non-static method
    private void start1() {
        System.out.println("start1");
    }

}
```